# Insert image into database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to insert an image into the database.

```
CREATE TABLE ImageTable
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50) ,
    Photo varbinary(max) 
)

INSERT INTO ImageTable (Id, Name, Photo) 
SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\caldophilus.jpg', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

It throws me an error.

> Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\caldophilus.jpg" does not exist.

Please Help.

Comment: Where is the image? On the `C:` drive on the **server** or a different machine?

Comment: SQL Server is looking at C:\ where it is installed. And if you have a newish OS, the SQL Server service account may not have access to C:\

Comment: How can i forget this, Thanks guys. It works now. The file in client pc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file is probably on your client PC.
Don't forget that C:\ refers to the server C drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE ImageTable
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50) ,
    Photo varbinary(max) 
)

INSERT INTO ImageTable (Id, Name, Photo) 
SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'D:\Test.ico', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

Path of the image must be your Server pc where SQl Server are running

Comment: Correct, but the question is already answered 5 years ago. Thanks