# how to insert an image into database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

when click save button it will stored in database and retrieve that image after clicking show button

```
Private Sub btnSve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSve.Click
    Dim data As IDataObject
    Dim bmap As Image
    data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
    If Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
        bmap = CType(Data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Image)
        picCapture.Image = bmap

        ''Stop Device Capture 
        ClosePreviewWindow()

        'Set Button 
        btnSave.Enabled = False
        btnStop.Enabled = False
        btnStart.Enabled = True

        'Set Save Dialog 
        sfdImage.FileName = ""
        sfdImage.Title = "Save Picture"
        sfdImage.Filter = "Bitmap|*.bmp|Jpeg|*.jpg|GIF|*.gif|PNG|*.png"

        ' If File Name Not Equal "" then Save The File 
        If sfdImage.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Select Case Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right$(sfdImage.FileName, 3)
                Case Is = "bmp"
                    bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
                Case Is = "jpg"
                    bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Case Is = "gif"
                    bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
                Case Is = "png"
                    bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            End Select
        End If

    End If

    data = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you even know how to read/write from a database? Or at least connect to a database?

Comment: Second result on google for keyphrase "insert an image into a database" is a link to [another question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291255/insert-image-into-database), which already has an answer. If it's not what you need, please take your time to clarify in your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're familiar with the [`System.Data.SqlClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace, this is how you could save the image:

```
Dim data As Byte()

Using stream As New MemoryStream()
    bmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    data = stream.GetBuffer()
End Using

Dim parameter As New SqlParameter("@DB_COLUMN_NAME", SqlDbType.Image, data.Length)

parameter.Value = data
mysqlcommand.Parameters.Add(parameter)
```