# Insert image in HSQL DB Manager

Tags: sql, image, insert, hsqldb

This is my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Box (BoxNr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Preis NUMERIC(7,2), Photo BLOB);
```

I'm working in Hsql and have no administrative rights. I tried using "VARBINARY(max)" as the type but it didn't recognize "max" and when i changed that to like 1000000 it started complaining about the "Openrowset" in 
`INSERT INTO PUBLIC.Box (BoxNr, Preis, Photo) SELECT 1, 100.00, BulkColumn  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Pferdebox.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Photo`

Could someone present me with another way or perhaps a step by step explanation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `OpenRowset` a function you wrote? It certainly isn't a standard SQL function (nor a standard HSQLDB function)

Comment: From what I've read online it sounded like that's part of the syntax. Could you please elaborate on the way BLOB is used?

Comment: Googled how to insert an image in a sql database and got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291255/insert-image-into-database. So i assumed that's how you do it. Can you please explain to me how to add it using BLOB?

Comment: That answer is for SQL Server, not for HSQLDB.

Comment: I'm using HSQL Database Manager and executing queries directly from there.

Comment: You are probably looking for `LOAD_FILE`: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N14171

Comment: Yes, the HSQLDB statement would look like this `INSERT INTO PUBLIC.Box (BoxNr, Preis, Photo) VALUES 1, 100.00, LOAD_FILE('c:\pFERDEBOX.JPG')`